# How to deploy a java web app to have a specific path?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a Tomcat server and wrote a simple java web app. When I deploy it on server, I can access it by the `localhost:8080/MyApp` path. What can I do to change this path to `localhost:8080/apps/MyApp`?

Answer (score 0):

In your **server.xml** change

```
<Context path="/MyApp" .../>
```

Comment: But where would server take the `apps` part of the path?

Comment: If you want 'localhost:8080/apps/MyApp' this path, you just add <Context path="/apps/MyApp"/> thats all

Comment: But server.xml is a server configuration file. Should I add `<Context .. tralala` for every app that I want to have a specific path?

Comment: You can add specific context by specifying it in the server.xml. If you want to take the easy way out, you can just use Tomcat's auto-deploy functionality and name the jar whatever context path you want it to be on, then put it in your webapps folder and restart Tomcat. 

Naming it ROOT.war will make it deploy on localhost:8080, whereas naming it MyApp.war will deploy it at localhost:8080/MyApp.

Comment: As Schaka mentioned you can also change the war name and restart your tomcat

Comment: Maybe I just cannot get something, but It is impossible to name file `apps/MyApp.war`.  Also I've tried adding the `<Context path="/apps/MyApp"/>` line to my server.xml, then restarted server and deployed MyApp.war, but it is in the `localhost:8080/MyApp` again.

Comment: Check your context.xml there should be something like <Context path="/MyApp"/> and delete it if exist. and yes you cant named like apps/MyApp.war. In this case you have to change the  server.xml

Comment: Yes, there was a `<Context...` in context.xml, I deleted it and deployed the newly built app to server. But now it is not shown in applications list and I cannot see it on `localhost:8080/apps/MyApp`! My next deployment attempt finishes with the `FAIL - War file "MyApp.war" already exists on server` and I cannot delete it via Manager. Gotta go delete it from the tomcat folder.

Comment: If its not shown on your applications list you couldnt deploy it, try to deleted existing war and rebuild and deploy that war.

Comment: What the heck!! I restarted the server severl times, rebuilt my app several times and nothing has changed. Then I decided to revert everythnig back (server.xml and context.xml changes), but now I have the same problem with indeployable application! Why this can happen?